# printing the Pchart to pdf using jspdf and html canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, charts, printing

not able to get the canvas element when the grah is inside the popup and i want to generate the popup without opening the popup.

It would be very helpful if i get some suggestions.

when the chart is inside the popup , not able to print to PDF without opening popup.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.